# Apigility Doctrine filter all fetch

Tags: php, filter, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, fetch

I'm on an ZF2 Apigility application with doctrine and **[the QueryBuilderFilter module](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-doctrine-querybuilder)**.

Based on **[this example](http://tomhanderson.blogspot.fr/2014/12/applying-doctrine-querybuilder-filters.html)**

I am trying to add a filter to all entities fetch that contain an `IdDealer` property.
For that I have attached a `FetchListener` to all fetch events :

```
DoctrineResourceEvent::EVENT_FETCH_PRE
DoctrineResourceEvent::EVENT_FETCH_ALL_PRE
```

And then I try to add a filter to the query if the entity is compatible with this filter.

```
public function __invoke(DoctrineResourceEvent $event)
{
    if ($event->getName() == DoctrineResourceEvent::EVENT_FETCH_ALL_PRE)
        $entity_class = $event->getEntity();
    else //DoctrineResourceEvent::EVENT_FETCH_PRE
        $entity_class = $event->getEntityClassName();


    /** Entity has idDealer so we filter for the user */
    if (method_exists($entity_class, 'getIdDealer')) {
        $em = $event->getObjectManager();
        $filterManager = $this->getServiceManager()->get('Zf\Doctrine\QueryBuilder\Filter\ManagerOrm');
        $filterManager->filter(
            $em->createQueryBuilder()->select('row')->from($entity_class, 'row'),
            $em->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor($entity_class),
            [
                'filter' => [
                    'type' => 'eq',
                    'field' => 'idDealer',
                    'value' => (int)$this->getUser()->getIdDealer()->getId(),
                ]
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

But I cannot get the filter to work.
I have found some info on internet that says that I should be able to retrieve the `QueryBuilder` from the event but it doesn't seem to be the case anymore.

Anyone with an idea on how to get this working ?

Answer (score 0):

I have just spent a good few hours trying to do something very similar.

The zf-doctrine-querybuilder guide suggests you can use Apigility Doctrine Events to filter querys:
https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-doctrine-querybuilder#use-with-apigility-doctrine

and links to an example: 
https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-doctrine-querybuilder/blob/master/docs/apigility.example.php

However I believe this suggestion and example code is now out of date due to the change "Remove QueryBuilder from DoctrineResourceEvents; add ObjectManager #182 ":
https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-doctrine/pull/182

I believe the way they want us to do this going forward is via custom Query Providers. See the following documentation that gives an example of how to bind a custom query provider to a specific entity:
https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-doctrine#query-providers

> Query Providers are available for all find operations. The find query
>   provider is used to fetch an entity before it is acted upon for all
>   DoctrineResource methods except create.
>
> A query provider returns a QueryBuilder object. By using a custom
>   query provider you may inject conditions specific to the resource or
>   user without modifying the resource. For instance, you may add a
>   $queryBuilder->andWhere('user = ' . $event->getIdentity()); in your
>   query provider before returning the QueryBuilder created therein.

If you want to look at an example Query Provider listener see ZF\Doctrine\QueryBuilder\Query\Provider\DefaultOrm:
https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-doctrine-querybuilder/blob/master/src/Query/Provider/DefaultOrm.php

For far I've not found any other solutions to getting a handle on the QueryBuilder being used as was previously possible when you could get it from the DoctrineResourceEvent object.

Hope this helps

Alex